# Do Netgear switches accept other brands of SFP+ modules and cables (e. g. Cisco)?

Tags: netgear, 10gbethernet, cable, sfp

Specifically, I'm looking to connect servers with Intel X520-DA1 10 Gigabit Ethernet cards to the 10Gbe ports of a Netgear ProSafe GS752TXS. Can I use Cisco SFP+ cables (SFP-H10GB-CU5M) and optical modules (SFP-10G-SR) with the Netgear?

All I can figure out from the Netgear documentation is that Netgear would be really happy if I bought their SFP+ cables and modules.

Answer (score 5):

SFP and SFP+ are standardized and generally are interchangeable in most situations. If a device requires coded SFP modules such as Cisco  then you need to use an OEM module, or disable coded SFP on your switch. In your situation however, Netgear generally does not require coded SFP so you can use any SFP, even a Cisco.